# Compare two list's values and get the difference

Tags: c#

I created a method that compares two lists' values and outputs the difference:

```
public static List<OT_Contact> Comparer(
    List<OT_Contact> security_owner,
    List<OT_Contact> borrower)
{
   List<OT_Contact> nonborrowertrustor = security_owner.Except(borrower).ToList();

   foreach (var nbt_list in nonborrowertrustor)
   {
      var list = nbt_list;
   }

   return nonborrowertrustor;
}
```

Can anyone tell me if there is something wrong with my code and how can I assign it to a variable, for example:

```
var result = Comparer(list1, list2);
```

Comment: `var list = nbt_list` does nothing. - thats probably whats wrong. If you use `.Except(..)` you should probably change to the overload that allows you to provide the used `IEqualityComparer` to test your `OT_Contact` for euqality. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336390(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @PatrickArtner how can i rewrite it?

Comment: `security_owner.Except(borrower, new InstanceOfIEqualityComparerYouImplementToCompareTwoOT_Contacts_SeeLinkInEarlierComment).ToList();`

Comment: How do you want to compare the items, on reference equality or value equality? What would value equality consist of (what fields would you compare and how would you compare them)? Does it matter if the lists have the same items but they are out of order? Does it matter if the two lists have the same items but there are duplicates in one list that aren't in the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you not using Linq?

```
var trustys = security_owner
    .Where(o => !borrower.Any(b=> b.Name == o.Name /* && compare more attributes from o and b */))
    .ToList();

return trustys;
```

this will filter all items from security owner which aren't in borrower, using

```
(b=> b.Name == o.Name && .....)
```

as "equality measure".

Example:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

internal class Program
{
    public class OT_Contact
    {
        public int Age;
        public string Email;
        public string Name;

        public OT_Contact(string name, string email, int age = int.MinValue)
        {
            Name = name;
            Email = email;
            Age = age;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return ($"{Name} {Email} " + (Age != int.MinValue ? Age.ToString() : "")).Trim();
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var owner = new List<OT_Contact>
            {
                new OT_Contact("paul","p@o", 5),
                new OT_Contact("paul","pppp@o"),
                new OT_Contact("mani","kkk"),
                new OT_Contact("olaf", "olaf", 22)
            };

        var borr = new List<OT_Contact>
            {
                new OT_Contact("paul","popel@o", 5),
                new OT_Contact("paul","pppp@o"),
                new OT_Contact("mani","kkk",99),
                new OT_Contact("olaf", "", 22)
            };

        var trust = owner.Where(o => !borr.Any(b => b.Name == o.Name && b.Email == o.Email)).ToList();

        System.Console.WriteLine("Owner:\n    " + string.Join("\n    ", owner));
        System.Console.WriteLine("\nBorrower:\n    " + string.Join("\n    ", borr));
        System.Console.WriteLine("\nTrustys:\n    " + string.Join("\n    ", trust));

        System.Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Output (Age is not important for equality, hence not inside the `Any`-Clause):

```
Owner:
    paul p@o 5
    paul pppp@o
    mani kkk
    olaf olaf 22

Borrower:
    paul popel@o 5
    paul pppp@o
    mani kkk 99
    olaf  22

Trustys:
    paul p@o 5
    olaf olaf 22
```

This example models the IEnumerable.Except(..) used in the question. It will find any `owner` that is not found in the `borr`ower list. The euqality-condition only takes `Name` and `Email` under consideration. If it finds an `borr`ower with the same `Name` and `Email` it will not output him in the resulting list.

Any `borr`ower that is only in the `owner` list won't make it into to the result either - getting any `borr`ower that is not in `owner` could be accomplished by simply swapping the lists around:

```
var onlyBorr = borr.Where(b => !owner.Any(o => o.Name == b.Name && o.Email == b.Email)).ToList();
```

A feasable implementation of an IEqualityComparer for this contrieved example could be

```
public class OT_ContactEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<OT_Contact>
{
    public bool Equals(OT_Contact x, OT_Contact y)
    {
        if (x == null || y == null)
            return false;

        return (x.Name == y.Name && x.Email == y.Email); 
    }

    public int GetHashCode(OT_Contact c)
        => (c.Name ?? "").GetHashCode() ^ (c.Email ?? "").GetHashCode(); 
}
```

which would allow the usage of IEnumerable.Except like this:

```
System.Console.WriteLine("\nIEquality:\n    " + string.Join("\n    ", 

    owner.Except(borr, new OT_ContactEqualityComparer())));
```

Comment: Note that you're only comparing one direction, so that if the second list has items not in the first list, you don't report on them.

Comment: @ErikE As per requirement of the statement that the questionair did :) - he uses IEnumerable.Except() which I modeled my solution after

Comment: Answers on StackOverflow should be of general utility to a wide audience. Therefore, even when answering a specific question, it is best to explain the characteristics of your algorithm and its limitations—what it does and does not do, and how to change it to do something else that many readers might be interested in doing. Can you agree that this would make your answer an overall more useful solution of greater general applicability? In that case, please consider explaining these details in your answer so that no one is led astray and can be helped more quickly.

Comment: @ErikE agreed & fixed

Comment: @JAIMEGAFFODJR - added the IEqualityComparer implementation as well. Feel free up upvote (arrow up) any answer that helped you out. Mark "your the best" answer as answer to your question: check the grey hookshape near the top of any answer that was most helpful.